# HTTP 400 message bad request on POST - views and serializers code not designed correctly

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I keep getting the following error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/creator_signup/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

Whenever I attempt to POST data from my AngularJS application to my Django backend.

On the client side, I have the following post made (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3M8a.jpg) from this code:

```
   function registerCreator(creatorData) {
      var url = envService.read('apiUrl') + "/creator_signup/";
      var dataJSON = {
        first_name: creatorData.firstName,
        last_name: creatorData.lastName,
        email: creatorData.email,
        youtube_channel_username: creatorData.username,
        youtube_channel_url: creatorData.url,
        youtube_channel_title: creatorData.title,
        youtube_channel_description: creatorData.description,
        photo: creatorData.photo,
        youtube_channel_start_date: creatorData.startDate,
        keywords: creatorData.keywords,
        no_of_subscribers: creatorData.noOfSubscribers,
        no_of_videos: creatorData.noOfVideos,
        no_of_views: creatorData.noOfViews,
        no_of_likes: creatorData.noOfLikes,
        no_of_dislikes: creatorData.noOfDislikes,
        location: creatorData.location,
        avg_views: creatorData.avgViews,
        gender: 0,
        password: creatorData.password
      };
      var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data: dataJSON
      };
      $log.info(req);
      return ($http(req).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    }

    function handleSuccess(response) {
      return response.data;
    }

    function handleError(response) {
      if (!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
        return($q.reject('An unknown error occurred.'));
      }
      return($q.reject(response.data.message));
    }
```

On the server side, I have:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^creator/$', views.CreatorList.as_view(), name="creator_list"),
    url(r'^creator/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/', views.CreatorDetail.as_view(), name="creator_detail"),
    url(r'^creator_signup/$', views.CreatorSignup.as_view(), name="creator_signup"),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**models.py**

```
class Creator(models.Model):
    """
    Creator model
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    youtube_channel_start_date = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    no_of_subscribers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_videos = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    no_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    avg_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET = 0
    GENDER_CHOICE_MALE = 1
    GENDER_CHOICE_FEMALE = 2
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET, 'Unset'),
        (GENDER_CHOICE_MALE, 'Male'),
        (GENDER_CHOICE_FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=GENDER_CHOICE_UNSET)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Creators"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name,self.last_name)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CreatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Creator objects
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Creator
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'youtube_channel_username', 'youtube_channel_url',
            'youtube_channel_title',
            'youtube_channel_description', 'photo', 'youtube_channel_start_date', 'keywords', 'no_of_subscribers',
            'no_of_videos', 'no_of_views', 'no_of_dislikes', 'location', 'avg_views'
        )
        read_only_fields = 'id'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Creator.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

class CreatorSignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Create Creator profile
    """
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    youtube_channel_username = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    youtube_channel_url = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    youtube_channel_title = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    youtube_channel_description = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    photo = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    youtube_channel_start_date = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    keywords = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    no_of_subscribers = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    no_of_videos = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    no_of_views = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    no_of_likes = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    no_of_dislikes = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    location = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    avg_views = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Creator
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'youtube_channel_username', 'youtube_channel_url',
            'youtube_channel_title',
            'youtube_channel_description', 'photo', 'youtube_channel_start_date', 'keywords', 'no_of_subscribers',
            'no_of_videos', 'no_of_views', 'no_of_dislikes', 'location', 'avg_views'
        )
        read_only_fields = 'id'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Creator.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatorList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    List all Creators
    HTTP: GET
    """
    queryset = Creator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatorSerializer


class CreatorDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    List one Creator
    HTTP: GET
    """
    queryset = Creator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatorSerializer

class CreatorSignup(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Creator signup
    HTTP POST
    """
    queryset = Creator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatorSignupSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I think the issue is in the views.py and serializers.py code, but I am not sure how to go about diagnosing it.

On the client side everything is logged out prior to the request and it looks ok.

Comment: Verify the header of `post` req. `'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` . Is it correct ?

Comment: This is the POST being made: https://imgur.com/a/syt64.

Comment: I mean, what requests are acceptable by server side API. Check that

Comment: I've set up the creator_signup endpoint to accept POST requests

Comment: @Troopers tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to `'content-type': 'application/json'` in `registerCreator` function. On the Django side data will be available under `request.body`, so your `CreatorSignup` view shoud look like this:

```
import json
...

class CreatorSignup(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Creator signup
    HTTP POST
    """
    queryset = Creator.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreatorSignupSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_body_dict = json.loads(request.body)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_body_dict)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

You also need to convert JSON into a string before sending it, so in `RegisterCreator` function, change `data: dataJSON` to `data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON)`.

Comment: Not getting an error anymore but nothing is posted to server

Comment: I've edited answer, please check it